# Custom group sort in devexpress xtra report

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have created a XtraReport with devexpress. I have grouped that report with a data field. In devexpress group field support only ascending and descending sort function. But I want to custom sort which I want. Can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [calculated field](https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/4813/detailed-guide-to-devexpress-reporting/shape-report-data/use-calculated-fields/calculated-fields-overview) and handle its `GetValue` event to implement custom sorting. See the following tutorial: [Sort Data by a Custom Field](https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/117213/detailed-guide-to-devexpress-reporting/shape-report-data/group-and-sort/sort-data-by-a-custom-field).